# Apache RewriteCond compare TIME

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with some Apache HTTP server-config.. Specifically I load a date in format YYMMDDHHmmss from a lookup-file via `RewriteMap`, which I try to compare to the current value from the `TIME` variable.

```
  RewriteMap lookup "txt:/path/to/file.flat"
  RewriteCond ${lookup:somekey|NOT_FOUND} NOT_FOUND [or]
  RewriteCond ${lookup:somekey|19700101010101} <%{TIME}
```

In `file.flat` would be something like this:

```
  somekey 20211010042042
```

It does not seem to work so far, which lead me here. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

The last straw I could imagine would otherwise be any kind of script I evaluate the expression with.

Comment: What is your complete rule? "I load a date in format YYMMDDHHmmss" - from the look of your file the format is YYYYMMDDHHmmss (as it would need to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond ${lookup:somekey|NOT_FOUND} NOT_FOUND [or]
> RewriteCond ${lookup:somekey|19700101010101} <%{TIME}
> ```

You've not included the complete rule (ie. `RewriteRule` directive) in your example. Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may decide to resolve this a different way.

The main problem with the above *condition* is that server variables of the form `%{VARIABLE}` are not expanded in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive). So `%{TIME}` is seen as literal text.

*Aside:* You don't need two conditions here. If *somekey* is not found in the rewrite map then both conditions would be *true* (by the perceived logic of these conditions).

If you are checking for *equality* then you can use a regex with an internal backreference ([for example](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035680/rewritemap-inside-rewritecond-doesnt-work-apache)). However, you are checking "less than" (lexicographic string comparison).

One way to resolve this is to assign the value of the rewrite map lookup to an environment variable and use this in an Apache expression (`RewriteCond expr` directive - available on Apache 2.4) to make the comparison. You can't lookup the rewrite map directly in the Apache expression.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LOOKUP_VALUE:${lookup:somekey}]
RewriteCond expr "reqenv('LOOKUP_VALUE') < %{TIME}"
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SUCCESS:1]
```

In your example you don't need to explicitly set a *DefaultValue* (should the key not be found in the rewrite map) since an *empty string* is always going to be "less than" `%{TIME}`. (The same as `19700101010101`.)

Comment: Wow, great and simple solution! Much better than a php or pearl script.
I was just wondering: is this therad-safe? I could possibly imagine 
one request evaluating line 2 with LOOKUP_VALUE holding an empty string
and one request writing a valid value into the LOOKUP_VALUE.

Comment: @fls Yes, pretty sure this is thread-safe. AFAIK Apache uses 1 thread per request.

Comment: I thought of a scenario, where two separate requests fall into this 'issue'...

Comment: @fls What's the "issue"?